# Simple Injector conditional registration based on a type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I am using MediatR to execute my requests. Inside the concrete handler my requirement is to execute, depending on the case, a command on one or more object instances.

Let's make a simple example. Suppose the request is to execute a topup for a mobile service customer. The requirement state that if the customer has more than one service activated, then the topup must be done on every service.

When the handler run it first load customer services

```
var services = context.Services.Where(c => c.CustomerId == customerId);
foreach ( var service in services ) {
   //Do the topup
}
```

To handle topups I have implemented it with the Command pattern. So I have the following model

[image: command pattern]

where the Invoker is exactly the MediatR handler instance. This is my receiver interface

```
internal interface IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : DefaultRequest
    where TResponse : DefaultResponse
{
        TResponse Apply( TRequest request );

        bool SupportsCommand( Type commandType );
}
```

and there are some different implementations based on network elements brand (Nokia, Ericsson, etc.)

```
internal abstract class BaseNokiaReceiver<TRequest, TResponse> 
    : IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : DefaultRequest
    where TResponse : DefaultResponse
{
    public BaseNokiaReceiver( ILogger logger, DataContext context, Service service )
        : base( logger, context, service ) {
    }

    public abstract TResponse Apply( TRequest request );
}
```

and a concrete one

```
internal class NokiaDataTrafficReceiver : BaseNokiaReceiver<TopupRequest, TopupResponse>
{
    public NokiaDataTrafficReceiver(ILogger logger, DataContext context, Service service) 
        : base(logger, context, service) {
    }

    public override TopupResponse Apply( TopupRequest request ) {
        //[...] Application code
    }
}
```

Because of the fact that a customer can have more than one service enabled on its account, I necessarily need to have more than one receiver with a single command class like, for example

```
internal abstract class AbstractCommand<TRequest, TResponse> 
    : ICommand<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : DefaultRequest
    where TResponse : DefaultResponse
{
    protected IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse> _receiver;

    public AbstractCommand( IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse> receiver ) {
        _receiver = receiver;
    }

    public abstract Task<TResponse> Apply( TRequest request );
}
```

and

```
internal class Reload : AbstractCommand<TopupRequest, TopupResponse>
{
    public Reload( IReceiver<TopupRequest, TopupResponse> receiver ) : base( receiver ) {
    }

    public async override Task<TopupResponse> Apply( TopupRequest request ) {
        var response = _receiver.Apply( request );
        return await Task.FromResult<TopupResponse>( response );
    }
}
```

The handler implementation then become something like the following

```
var services = context.Services.Where( c => c.CustomerId = customerId );
foreach ( var service in services ) {
    IReceiver<TopupRequest, TopupResponse> receiver = null;
    if ( service is VoiceService ) {
        receiver = new VoiceAccountReceiver();
    }
    else if ( service is DataService ) {
        receiver = new DataTrafficReceiver();
    }
    Reload command = new Reload( receiver );
    var result = command.Apply( input );
}
```

And each receiver does a single specific topup.

Actually the instantiation of receivers happens in code and I would like to change it in a way that I can use the DI container.

By talking in pseudo code I would like to register an instance of a Receiver strictly tied to a Type, e.g.

```
container.Register<IReceiver<TopupRequest, TopupResponse>, VoiceAccountReceiver>()
    .WhenParameterofType<VoiceService>();
container.Register<IReceiver<TopupRequest, TopupResponse>, DataTrafficReceiver>()
    .WhenParameterofType<DataService>();
```

and so resolve the type at runtime with

```
container.GetInstance<IReceiver<TopupRequest, TopupResponse>>( typeof(service) );
```

Comment: This question is missing a lot pf important information required to get answered. 1. What is the relationship beyween TypeA and Receiver1? Without such description, you can't define a condition. 2. The sample is not a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, some context is missing. 3. What is MyCommand and why are you injecting a dependency into its constructor. 4. In general, it's hard to see what it is you are trying to do, and why you need receivers and commands on top of requests and handlers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can understand your issues with the question. The architecture of all the classes is complex and there are many actor involved. I have tried to completely rewrite the question by giving more context and hopefully making it more clear. Hope this helps to clarify the context.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, you are missing some type information that allows you to distinguish at compile-time between operations. This seems obvious, because you are adding type-checks on `VoiceService` and `DataService`.

So what you could try is adding that type information to the `IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse>` abstraction. For instance:

```
interface IReceiver<TRequest, TResponse, TService> { }
```

This way, `VoiceAccountReceiver` could be implemented as follows:

```
class VoiceAccountReceiver : IReceiver<TopupRequest, TopupResponse, VoiceService>
```

This allows the correct receiver be resolved based on its available type information. Preferably, your handler should take a dependency on sort of mediator abstraction. The mediator implementation will be responsible for calling back into the container to resolve the correct type.

For instance:

```
var services = context.Services.Where(c => c.CustomerId == customerId);
foreach ( var service in services ) {
    var result = this.receiverMediator.Apply(input, service);
}
```

Your `IReceiverMediator` can be defined as follows:

```
interface IReceiverMediator
{
    TResponse Apply<TRequest, TService>(TRequest input, object service)
        where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>;
}
```

And a Simple Injector specific implementation can be defined as follows:

```
class SimpleInjectorReceiverMediator : IReceiverMediator
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public SimpleInjectorReceiverMediator(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public TResponse Apply<TRequest, TService>(TRequest input, object service)
        where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
    {
        Type receiverType =
            typeof(IReceiver<,,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TRequest), typeof(TResponse), service.GetType());

        dynamic receiver = container.GetInstance(receiverType);

        return (TResponse)receiver.Action();
    }
}
```

This way there are no conditional registrations *at all*. You can simply batch-register all receivers as follows:

```
container.Register(typeof(IReceiver<,,>), assemblies);
container.Register<IReceiverMediator>(new SimpleInjectorReceiverMediator(container));
```

Comment: Hello Steven. Thanks a lot. I have tried to implement your solution but there is something that must escape me. First of all, does `IReceiverMediator` substitute the command or is used inside the command class? Also, what is that `(TResponse)receiver.Action()`? Do you mean `(TResponse)receiver.Apply( request )`? Moreover, I would need to change also the command class because of the fact that adding a new type parameter to IReceiver will need the same parameter in the command as the receiver is injected in the constructor. I have tried to follow your suggestion but no luck at the moment

Comment: I have added some further details on the pattern implementation

Comment: hi @Lorenzo, please note that my answer is written without understanding your domain, and your design. So what I did was give you an idea of how adding compilable metadata could help you solve the problem. I don't know whether the command should be moved inside the mediator or not, that's something you will have to figure out for yourself. I do want to note though that the problem you are having is not one with your DI Container, since you will have the same kind of trouble with _all_ containers. It's mainly a _design_ problem.

Comment: Dont misunderstand me, I did not asked for a solution from your side. However it seems strange to me when you state "It's mainly a design problem" because I am using standard patterns design and not something made by myself. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, you shouldn't be supprized to see that the use of standard design patterns don't give you an elegant solution that solves your problems. It's all about using the correct patterns at the right places, which can be really daunting, to say the least. Good example of this is the Command pattern that you are using. Not saying that it isn't the right pattern for you right now, but IMO it hardly ever is a good solution, because it mixes runtime data with behavior and strongly couples the command's consumer with the dependency. For that exact reason, MediatR separates messages from handlrs

Comment: what about [this link](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key)? do you think it can help by keying the types of the service?

Comment: Sure. That allows you to build a dictionary with registrations that can be resolved by a `XXXService` type, but you will still have to pass on that information to some sort of mediator so it can resolve the correct instance from the dictionary.